# Adding class to a hyperlink

Tags: html, class, content-management-system, hyperlink

My CMS wont let me add a thickbox class to a hyperlink inline. It just keeps stripping out the class when I save.

Are there any ways to enforce tis class or a workaround?

Thanks

R

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're editing a single page via a WYSIWYG editor, such as TinyMCE or similar. You have to check the editor's settings and make sure it won't strip the `class` attribute from your content. This will fix it, provided that the attributes aren't stripped in PHP on content submission.

Comment: Hi My CMS is written in.NET. How would I checlk the editor settings?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's PHP, .NET, Perl or other language :). I don't know where the settings reside as I've no idea what CMS you're using. Look for it in the admin panel and if there isn't a setting for it, you'll have to dig through the files on the server and find the editor's configuration there. It could also be called directly in the page code, it varies across sites.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the class with the link editor if you've tried in source/html mode, or vice versa.

Also, I know some of these editors have some tags for content it shouldn't traverse through. Can't help since I don't know the CMS you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ID to the link you can have such code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("MyLink").className = "thickbox";
}
```

Otherwise can you set custom attributes without CMS removing them?